# Excel: Querying Web/Sharepoint in Drop-Down

Tags: excel, web, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a very small Excel file which queries an Online/Sharepoint Excel file.
I don't want to import all the data as this increases the final size of the document (I know I can make a VBA Macro to delete the data but I can't reply on the people using the spreadsheet to run this macro).

Ideally, I would like to have each section in a drop down list; ie 1st Drop Down selects **category** of item, which directly influences the 2nd Drop Down of **Manufacturer** which directly influences **Model** etc. with each section only being queried as it is required.
Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

you can ask your macro to be triggered on an automatic event without replying on the user.

Could you define : category, item, Manufacturer, Model and section?
with words like : Sheet, Workbook, Row, Range
Or And give a sample spreadsheet

Comment: So far that seems like using a macro is the only way;

I haven't yet compiled a sample spreadsheet, but Im sure I can split it into a separate workbook (referencing Category), sheet (referencing Manufacturer), row (model) etc.